# Rails N-Table Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around the automagical-ness of Rails. Right now I have 4 different tables that are all related to each other in one way or another but I'm having a hard time representing that in my application. I was able to do this in PHP/MySQL without much of an issue but translating it to a new framework hasn't been as easy as I expected.

Right now I have 4 tables but I will have many more down the road that mimic this same structure. The four current tables are (rails class representation):

- User
- InterestPage
- InterestPageCategory
- InterestPageMap

Each User has_many InterestPage(s) through InterestPageMap

Each InterestPage belongs_to InterestPageCategory which, in turn, has_many InterestPage(s)

When I add a new InterestPage for a given User I first need to make sure that the InterestPageCategory exists and that the InterestPage is linked back to the correct category. What is the best way to go about this kind of relationship?

The method I'm using now is giving me this error:

```
uninitialized constant User::InterestPageCategory
```

So I figure I'm pretty far off from what I'm trying to do. My User class code looks something like this:

```
has_many :interest_page_maps, foreign_key: "fb_id", dependent: :destroy
...
category = InterestPageCategory.where(category: resp["category"]).first_or_create
# Then I try to add the page with the correct category
page = InterestPage.where(resp[0]).first_or_create do |interestpage|
    # Should I be adding the page through the category in this block?
    interestpage.name = resp["name"]
    interestpage.id = resp["id"]
end
```

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are the category = and page = parts in a method?

Comment: They're in the same method under the User model. Basically the method calls the Facebook Graph API and returns a set of the user's liked pages.

Comment: Have you got anything in the method like `self.interest_pages << page`

Comment: No nothing like that in the method.

I made a new project just to test the basic structure of the relationship that I want to make and the test project works which means I've got a typo or something in this project causing problems. I'll post here when I have a minute to track it down, have some other client work to finish up today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a typo on my part. Rails references the **file name** not the **class name** when generating relationships, i.e.:

The file containing the InterestPageCategory class was named interest_page_categories.rb. This was incorrect, the file needed to have the name interest_page_category.rb (singular vs plural) in order for Rails to "see" the class I was trying to reference.

Hope this helps someone else, don't forget to check your naming people!